# "Хрущевки"

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Нужны ли кавычки в слове "хрущевка" (то есть, дом постройки времен Хрущева)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, кавычки не нужны. Слово давно вошло в словари.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно. Пример - коммуналки.